Looking for a resolution for pac4j SAML SP to connect IDP
We have successfully created SP Metadata using pac4j.
Next step is to connect the Hana IDP from our application.
With different sample code from documentation and forum I have written below code:
SAML2Configuration cfg = new SAML2Configuration("sampletestKeystore.jks", "Password@123", "Password@1231", "idp_metadata.xml");  //Hana IDP Metadata

cfg.setMaximumAuthenticationLifetime(6000);

cfg.setServiceProviderEntityId("BOE_SP_ID");

cfg.setServiceProviderMetadataPath("sp-meta-downloaded_Rajib.xml");

cfg.setPostLogoutURL(http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/SampleWeb/logout.html);

cfg.setSpLogoutRequestBindingType(http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/SampleWeb/logoutbinding.html);

SAML2Client saml2Client = new SAML2Client(cfg);

saml2Client.setName("BOE Client");

saml2Client.setCallbackUrl(http:// xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/SampleWeb/BOE.html);

final Clients clients = new Clients();

clients.setClients(saml2Client);

With the code above, IDP[Hana] is not receiving any request. Can somebody please suggest, if I am missing something important in the code? I am getting the below logs on executing the above code.
Pac4j logs I am receiving as:
2024-07-17 05:58:34 INFO  org.pac4j.saml.util.Configuration - Bootstrapping OpenSAML configuration via Pac4j...
2024-07-17 05:58:34 WARN  o.p.core.adapter.FrameworkAdapter - No framework adapter found. Using DefaultFrameworkAdapter...
2024-07-17 05:58:34 INFO  o.o.c.config.InitializationService - Initializing OpenSAML using the Java Services API
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#ripemd160
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-ripemd160
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-ripemd160
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha1-rsa-MGF1
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha224-rsa-MGF1
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha256-rsa-MGF1
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha384-rsa-MGF1
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha3-224-rsa-MGF1
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha3-256-rsa-MGF1
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha3-384-rsa-MGF1
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha3-512-rsa-MGF1
2024-07-17 05:58:35 INFO  o.o.x.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha512-rsa-MGF1`

For getting the answer to my queries, I am done good amount of R&D in below places:

https://groups.google.com/g/pac4j-users
https://github.com/pac4j/buji-pac4j-demo
https://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients.html
-https://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/saml.html


Which pac4j implementation do you use (https://www.pac4j.org/implementations.html)? What are the pac4j DEBUG logs when you hit an URL protected by the SAML2Client?

Hi jleleu,
Our product is based on J2EE technology and backend is Java & C++ based stack.
For this POC for the Pac4j SAML based, I was using core Java [J2SE] standalone application.
The code snippet[I posted] is totally on based on J2SE.
There is a security incident in our side, which has let us think in the direction.
Based on your last question, I am looking for options of “pac4j/jee-pac4j” for the POC.
BTW, can you please let me know, to use SAML of pac4j, is it mandatory to use one of the implementation from https://www.pac4j.org/implementations.html?
Regards
Rajib

No, it's not mandatory to use one of the pac4j implementations because pac4j is a security engine by itself. Though, it is generally much easier to use a pac4j implementation.
